Бот не отвечает на команды в канале Telegram
Хочу сделать так, чтобы бот мог отсылать сообщения в канал. С группами он взаимодействует, а вот с каналами нет. На канале у него есть все права.
package tg

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
)

var UserId []int64

func Telegram() (*tgbotapi.BotAPI, error) {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(os.Getenv("API_KEY"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(-1)

    updates := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

    go func() {
        for update := range updates {
            if update.Message == nil {
                continue
            }

            if !update.Message.IsCommand() {
                continue
            }

            msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, "")

            switch update.Message.Command() {
            case "start":
                UserId = append(UserId, update.Message.Chat.ID)
                msg.Text = "Парсер запущен."

            default:
                msg.Text = "Неизвестная команда."
            }

            if _, err := bot.Send(msg); err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }
    }()
    return bot, nil
}


